# Using autoML Rest API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-404, google-authentication

I'm working on a JAVA application that uses Google autoML Rest API to classify images based on a trained model (I trained the model using the web platform directly). 
I'm having trouble to send any request to use this API to make predictions or get the existing models, I'm always having a 404 error.

I doubt I don't have the needed permissions to make the call, I used OAuth2 to authenticate but still having the same problem. I'm pretty sure that the authentification is correct because I tried it on another API that requires it and it worked fine.

Furthermore, I've been working with the google video intelligence API and I didn't have this problem.
for example, if i would like to get the existing models, I send the following GET request:

Request URL : https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/Project-ID/models

Error message : The requested URL 
        `/v1beta1/Project-ID/models` was not found on this server.

Any idea of the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [listing models](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/models#list-models), the endpoint that AutoML it's using is the following:

```
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/models
```

Where ${PROJECT_ID} should be your current [Project ID](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not mentioned here in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/list). But I've tried it and it's working now! thank you very much! But I don't understand why there is a difference in their docs!

Comment: Is it working for you by doing the [curl command](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/models#list-models)? I've had to set the [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) for the service account authentication

Comment: yes the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is already set